# Logistic map (discrete dynamical system) vs logistic differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have to roughly illustrate the logistic discrete dynamical system (as a model for population growth) to some non mathematics students. I'm not an analyst or an expert of dynamical systems.

Looking things up in the internet, I find the logistic map

$$x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n)$$

with initial condition $x_0\in [0,1]$, and where $r\in[0,4]$ is a parameter (the condition $0\leq r \leq 4$ guarantees that $x_n$ doesn't escape the unit interval $[0,1]$ throughout the evolution of the system). Here $x_n$ represents the ratio between the population at time $n$ and the total population the environment is able to support.

I find also different behaviors according to the value of the parameter $r\in[0,4]$. For example,

1. For $0<r\leq 1$ there's extinction of the population.
2. For $1<r\leq 3$ the sequence tends to a stable equilibrium $x_\infty:=1-1/r$.
3. For $3<r\leq 1+\sqrt{6}$ there's convergence to a period-$2$ cycle.
4. For $1+\sqrt{6}<r\leq r^*$ (where $r^*$ is a certain constant) several bifurcations occur with limit a cycle of period that doubles as $r$ traverses that range.
5. For $r>r^*$ there's chaotic behavior.

I would expect that a similar span of different behaviors also happens for the logistic *differential* equation

$$\dot{x}(t)=rx(t)(1-x(t))$$

upon varying the parameter $r$. **But** on the internet I found no reference to anything like this. On the contrary, many pages care to solve the differential equation explicitely and illustrate the solution, which is the famous *logistic function*: the S-shaped increasing curve (depending on $r$) with a horizontal asymptote and an inflection point. It seems this solution is obtainable no matter what $r$ is. **This** looks only like case number 2. of the discrete dynamical system above.

> So where are the analogous to cases 1.,3.,4. and 5. where the time is continuous??

Or am I misunderstanding some aspects of how a continuous-time dynamical system gets discretized?

Also,

> Which correspondence is there between the $r$ of the discrete version and the $r$ of the continuous version?

Answer (score 4):

**Only some elements**

A differential equation and it associated discretized problem may have different stability behaviors depending on the way you perform the discretization. See for example [Wikipedia - discretization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization), paragraph *Approximations*.

Nevertheless, approximating $\dot{x}(t) = rx(t)(1-x(t))$ by $x_{n+1}=r x_n(1-x_n)$ is rather strange. It should be better discretized by $x_{n+1} -x_n =r x_n(1-x_n)$. Because usually 
$$\dot{x}(t) = \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{t_{n+1}-t_n} =x_{n+1}-x_n$$ if you consider equal discretization of the time.

Comment: I exactly thought the same thing: the ODE should be discretized by $x_{n+1}-x_n=rx_n(1-x_n)$ because the finite difference ratio $(x_{n+1}-x_n)/1$ plays the role of $dx/dt$. But I don't know...

Comment: In the paragraph you cite (of the wikipedia link) it seems they're considering *linear* ODEs, while the logistic is nonlinear - not sure how this affects the continuous/discrete relationship.

Comment: It is even worse... if You already have issue with linear problems!

Answer (score 2):

In the logistic equation you get transforming it as Bernoulli equation
$$
\frac{d}{dt}x(t)^{-1}=r(1-x(t)^{-1})\implies x(t)^{-1}=1+ce^{-rt}.
$$ 
Now compare the values for $t$ and $t+h$,
$$
x(t+h)^{-1}-1 = ce^{-rt-rh}=e^{-rh}(x(t)^{-1}-1).
$$
For the sequence $x_k=x(kh)$ you get thus the recursion formula
$$
x_{k+1}=\frac{x_k}{1-e^{-rh}+e^{-rh}x_k}
$$
which looks rather different than the logistic map.

---

Any sane discretization using the Euler method or similar would use a sufficiently small $h$, so that in the Euler forward discretization $$x_{k+1}=x_k(1+hr)-hrx_k^2.$$ To get to the normal form one would have to rescale $y_k=ax_k$, so that then $$y_{k+1}=y_k(1+hr)-\frac{hr}ay_k^2=(1+hr)y_k\left(1-\frac{hr}{a(1+hr)}y_k\right)$$ giving $a=\frac{hr}{1+hr}$. This is indeed case $2$ in the list, with equilibrium at $y_\infty=1-\frac1{1+hr}=\frac{hr}{1+hr}=a$ or translated back at $x_\infty=1$.

Comment: Ok, this is to say the recursion you get depends heavily on how you choose to discretize, I assume? But is it relevant to the question? Which is the discretization method in the OP case, and does it lead to different phenomena (differences between the continuum and the discrete)?

Comment: Too long for a comment, added remark on discretization to the answer. One can conclude that the interesting phenomena happen when $h$ is so large that the discretization error can no longer be classified as $O(h^2)$ as the higher order terms are equally large or even dominate.

Comment: So it's true that chaotic features are not present in the continuous model but appear only once I discretize in that specific way?

Comment: The issue is discussed here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285946802_The_Numerical_Connection_between_Map_and_its_Differential_Equation_Logistic_and_Other_Systems